# How to split a cell inside in table by ratio

Tags: html, css

I wish to split a cell inside an HTML table by ratio.

For example, I wish to see a green div that will take 60% of the cell, and next to it, a red div that will take the remaining 40%.

***Note: the divs must be empty from any text***

Why does my code not work?

```css
.passDiv {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.failDiv {
  background-color: rgba(211, 0, 0, 1);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Execution Time</th>
    <th>Steps Passed / Failed</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test AAA</td>
    <td>Passed</td>
    <td>00:02:30</td>
    <td>
      <div class="passDiv" width="60%"></div>
      <div class="failDiv" width="40%"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note: The divs should be empty, a solution where I need to enter text in the Divs isn't good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
td {
    max-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.passDiv {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

.failDiv {
  background-color: rgba(211, 0, 0, 1);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Execution Time</th>
  <th width='40%'>Passed </th>
  <th width='60%'>Failed</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Test AAA</td>
  <td>Passed</td>
  <td>00:02:30</td>
  <td width='40%' class="passDiv"></td>
  <td width='60%' class="failDiv"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to split the divs without writing something inside them?

Comment: It split the divs with or without text yet.

Comment: @TalAngel Try putting a height on the div with css.

Comment: Updated snippet with no text inside

Answer (score 1):

```css
.passDiv {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  width:60%;
  float:left;
}

.failDiv {
  background-color: rgba(211, 0, 0, 1);
  display: block;
   width:40%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Execution Time</th>
    <th>Steps Passed / Failed</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test AAA</td>
    <td>Passed</td>
    <td>00:02:30</td>
    <td>
    <div class="passDiv">Pass</div> 
    <div class="failDiv">Fail</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```